# Handling different actions based on click event and search in Django plotly dash

Tags: django, callback, plotly-dash

I am working on Django plotly dash app and have some callback functions that are triggered when two input elements `sidebar-graph` (it is a bar chart) and `search-top2vec-input` (it is a search box) receive updates. The callback function, `update_charts_word_graph_app2`, has the following signature:

```
   def _register_app2_callbacks(self):
        @self.app2.callback(
            [
                Output("sidebar-content", "children"),
                Output("network-graph-chart", "children"),
                Output("graph-title-text", "children"),
                Output("word-cloud-title-text", "children"),
                Output("top-10-urls-title-text", "children"),
                Output("word-cloud-graph", "children"),
                Output("top-10-urls-graph", "children"),
                Output("search-error-message", "children"),
                Output("ls-loading-output-top2vec", "children"),
            ],
            [
                Input("sidebar-graph", "clickData"),
                Input("search-top2vec-input", "value"),
            ],
        )
        def update_charts_word_graph_app2(click_data, search_value):
            return self._update_charts_word_graph(click_data, search_value)  # Return all outputs
```

The issue I'm facing is that when I click on the bar chart, the click_data is not `None` anymore and then I try to perform a search, the search functionality doesn't work as expected because the click event data is still present.

Here's the relevant part of the code:

```
def _update_charts_word_graph(self, click_data=None, search_value=None):
        """
        update the word graphs and related components based on clicke data or search value.

        Args:
            click_data (dict, optional): Click data from the graph. Defaults to None.
            search_value (str, optional): Search value from the input. Defaults to None.

        Returns:
            List: List of components to be updated
        """

        object_graph = Graph()

        if click_data is not None:
            print("." * 20)
            print("click")
            print(click_data)
            print(search_value)
            print("." * 20)
            click_components = self._process_click_data(object_graph, click_data)
            return click_components

        if search_value is not None and search_value.strip() != "":
            print("*" * 20)
            print("search_value")
            print(click_data)
            print(search_value)
            print("*" * 20)
            search_components = self._process_search_keywords(object_graph, search_value)
            return search_components

        sidebar_content = self._bar_chart_h(
            self.topic_model.topic_words,
            self.topic_model.topic_sizes,
            self.topic_model.topic_nums,
        )

        all_topic_words = [word for sublist in self.topic_model.topic_words for word in sublist]

        # Generate co-occurrence graph for all topic words
        figure, _ = object_graph.co_occurence_graph(
            data=[all_topic_words],
            window_size=2,
            max_nodes=80,
            max_edges=160,
            node_weights=None,
            mandatory_words=None,
            filter_="BFS",
            remove_nodes_without_edges=True,
        )

        word_cloud = self._generate_all_topic_word_cloud(all_topic_words)
        title_text = "All Topic Words"

        components = [
            sidebar_content,
            dcc.Graph(id="word-graph", className="word-graph", figure=figure),
            title_text,
            title_text,
            title_text,
            word_cloud,
            word_cloud,
            "",
            "",
        ]

        return components
```

I need assistance in solving this issue. I want to perform different actions based on the click event ( if click on the bar chart) and the search input (if a search is performed). how can I ensure that the search functionality works even if the `click_data` is not`None`.
By the way, I tried something like:

```
      if click_data is not None:
            print("." * 20)
            print("click")
            print(click_data)
            print(search_value)
            print("." * 20)
            click_components = self._process_click_data(object_graph, click_data)
            click_data = None # making the ckick_data None 
            return click_components
```

But it is not helping.

after two days I figure it out with the help of @ericlavault.
this is now working:

```
    def _register_app2_callbacks(self):
        @self.app2.callback(
            [
                Output("sidebar-content", "children"),
                Output("network-graph-chart", "children"),
                Output("graph-title-text", "children"),
                Output("word-cloud-title-text", "children"),
                Output("top-10-urls-title-text", "children"),
                Output("word-cloud-graph", "children"),
                Output("top-10-urls-graph", "children"),
                Output("search-error-message", "children"),
                Output("ls-loading-output-top2vec", "children"),
            ],
            [
                Input("sidebar-graph", "clickData"),
                Input("search-top2vec-input", "value"),
            ],
        )
        def update_charts_word_graph_app2(click_data, search_value, callback_context):
            return self._update_charts_word_graph(
                click_data=click_data, search_value=search_value, ctx=callback_context
            )  # Return all outputs

def _update_charts_word_graph(self, click_data=None, search_value=None, ctx=None):

        object_graph = Graph()

        if ctx and ctx.triggered:
            triggered_id = ctx.triggered[0]["prop_id"].split(".")[0]
        else:
            triggered_id = None

        if triggered_id == "sidebar-graph" and click_data is not None:
            return self._process_click_data(object_graph, click_data)

        if triggered_id == "search-top2vec-input" and search_value.strip() != "":
            return self._process_search_keywords(object_graph, search_value)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to distinguish which component has triggered the callback in order to determine the action to perform. Fortunately, Dash provides a global variable that precisely allows to do that, [`dash.callback_context`](https://dash.plotly.com/advanced-callbacks#determining-which-input-has-fired-with-dash.callback_context) (which is available only inside callbacks).

In a standard Dash app, the way to go would be something like :

```py
def _update_charts_word_graph(self, click_data=None, search_value=None):
    ctx = dash.callback_context
    object_graph = Graph()

    #if click_data is not None:
    if ctx.triggered_id == 'sidebar-graph' and click_data is not None:
        click_components = self._process_click_data(object_graph, click_data)
        return click_components

    # if search_value is not None and search_value.strip() != "":
    if ctx.triggered_id == 'search-top2vec-input' and search_value.strip() != "":
        search_components = self._process_search_keywords(object_graph, search_value)
        return search_components

    # ...
```

In a DjangoDash app though, it is preferable to use the [`kwargs['callback_context']`](https://django-plotly-dash.readthedocs.io/en/latest/extended_callbacks.html) argument rather than using the global variable mentioned above :

> The `callback_context` argument is provided in addition to the
> `dash.callback_context` global variable. As a rule, the use of global
> variables should generally be avoided. The context provided by
> django-plotly-dash is not the same as the one provided by the
> underlying Dash library [...].
> **The
> use of this global variable in any asychronous or multithreaded
> application is not supported, and the use of the callback argument is
> strongly recommended for all use cases.**

```py
@self.app2.callback(...)
def update_charts_word_graph_app2(*args, **kwargs):
    return self._update_charts_word_graph(*args, **kwargs)
```

```py
def _update_charts_word_graph(self, *args, **kwargs):
    click_data = args[0]
    search_value = args[1]
    ctx = kwargs['callback_context']

    object_graph = Graph()

    #if click_data is not None:
    if ctx.triggered_id == 'sidebar-graph' and click_data is not None:
        click_components = self._process_click_data(object_graph, click_data)
        return click_components

    # if search_value is not None and search_value.strip() != "":
    if ctx.triggered_id == 'search-top2vec-input' and search_value.strip() != "":
        search_components = self._process_search_keywords(object_graph, search_value)
        return search_components

    # ...
```

Comment: thanks for your response.  Unfortunately, I got now the following error:  

``` culturecrawler-web-1  |     print(ctx.triggered_id)
culturecrawler-web-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/dash/_callback_context.py", line 19, in assert_context
culturecrawler-web-1  |     if not context_value.get():
culturecrawler-web-1  | LookupError: <ContextVar name='callback_context' at 0x7f79f7a894f0> 
```

Comment: What is your dash version ?

Comment: I missed the fact you were bulding a django-plotly-dash app ! I edited my answer, hope that will help (couldn't test it though, your feedback is welcome).

Comment: thanks again for help, but the kwargs si empty dict

Comment: You will need to handle args and kwargs from the decorated @callback function and pass them along to the actual handler. Just added the missing code snippet.